# Trying to install mysql-server and it throws a mariadb error

Tags: apt, mysql

While trying to install mysql-server, I get this error:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mariadb-client-10.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-client-10.1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,239 kB of archives.
After this operation, 41.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-apt-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mariadb-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-ansi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php7.0-readline' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php7.0-opcache' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mariadb-server-core-10.1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mariadb-client-core-10.1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-pseudomap' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ssl-cert' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php7.0-cli' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php-xml' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php-cli' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ncurses-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php5-readline' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'systemd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcwidget3v5:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'node-spdx-correct' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php7.0-xml' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdbi-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 46362 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-client-10.1 (10.1.23-9+deb9u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/bin/mysqladmin' to '/usr/bin/mysqladmin.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do here?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` in a while?